# Should the current discussion on Zeno's Paradox be reopened?

Tags: discussion

About it one can cite wiki as to the significance. [Zeno's paradox](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/782/is-zenos-paradox-resolved) should be taught as history of mathematics - and solely as history - these days!

Wiki states only some historians of mathematics and mathematicians believe the paradox is resolved.  Would it be interesting to take opinions from mathematicians and historians of mathematics on the matter?

Comment: Care to discuss your probable downvote HDE226868?

Comment: Wasn't me; I'm thinking about writing an answer. It'd be interesting if that person could explain, though. By the way, you can use the '@' symbol to automatically ping someone who's been active on a post. So just write '@HDE226868' if you want to ping me. Or you can find me in chat; pinging works the same way there.

Comment: This question can be reopened if it is edited to something like "How did Zeno's paradox influence the development of mathematics?" It might be of interest since the original question is based on a misunderstanding of history, the amount of "calculus" needed to "resolve" the paradox (summing the geometric series) was already known in antiquity, Aristotle pointed it out, and Archimedes gave a proof by method of exhaustion rigorous even by modern standards. But it did little to answer conundrums about the nature of space, time and motion that the paradox was really aimed at.

Comment: @Conifold I'd re-open it if it was edited, certainly. Paul deleted it yesterday; I may undelete it for him.

Answer (score 4):

Your question was closed and, in my opinion, should *remain* closed, because you're simply not asking a question about the history of science and mathematics. Here's your main question:

> [...] is there anymore reason to teach it in a philosophy course? Why not teach it in a history of mathematics course as a flawed line of thinking that, when overcome, could've potentially laid the foundations for calculus!?

It is obvious that this is a question about teaching practices. Whether some (perhaps historically important) topic is taught in a philosophy course or a mathematics course at universities is clearly not a question about history, and therefore off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 3):

I'm HDE 226868, the guy who closed it. You're right in that I've "never truly published enough mathematics to know the historical background". In fact I've never published *anything*, because I'm still in high school. But does that matter? Does a person really have to have "published mathematics" in order to be qualified to answer a question? (On the flip side, is a person qualified to answer a question just because they have "published mathematics"?)

I'd say no, because there's a difference between mathematics and the *history* of mathematics. Could I answer a question about quantum field theory? Most Definitely not. But could I answer a question about the *history* of quantum field theory? Absolutely (Bring it on!). *Closing* a question is something else entirely - and I think it requires less knowledge of the subject than answering (or even commenting on it). In this case, the question was not focused on history, and so I closed it as off-topic.

Now to the meat of it. Should it be re-opened or closed? Why?

I see Danu beat me to it; my reasons were similar to those. Curses. :-)

Comment: Apologies for directing so much at you!  Perhaps the thread stays open, perhaps it stays closed?